# Returning array object by filtering it's nested size variants

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the list of products that i want to filter by their `varriants.size`

Staring point, data I'm receiving:

```js
const t1 = [
  {
    name: 'Product 1',
    variants: [
      { size: 'sm', sku: '1' },
      { size: 'md', sku: '2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 2',
    variants: [{ size: 'lg', sku: '4' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 3',
    variants: [
      { size: 'sm', sku: '5' },
      { size: 'lg', sku: '6' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 4',
    variants: [{ size: 'sm', sku: '7' }],
  },
]
```

By using `['sm', 'md']` I want to filter above object and return this result

End goal / expected results

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'Product 2',
    variants: [{ size: 'lg', sku: '4' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 3',
    variants: [{ size: 'lg', sku: '6' }],
  },
]
```

What I've tried so far but not getting full data / missing properties.

```js
const filter = ['sm', 'md']

const arr = t1.map((e) => {
  const filter = e.variants.filter((f) => {
    return filter.includes(f.size)
  })
  return filter
})
```

But only getting `varriants` object, rest of the data is missing.

This screenshot is bad example, this one is only filtering ['sm'] but in this case I have multiple filter option `['sm', 'md']`

[image]

Comment: you are filtering only variant arrays, and returning that array, when you have to filter the object so instead of : `const filter = e.variants.filter((f) => {
    return filter.includes(f.size)
  })` you need to reverse it only like : `const filter = e.filter((f) => {
    return filter.variants.includes(f.size)
  })`

Comment: it's more understandable and easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const 
  t1 = [
    { name: 'Product 1', variants: [{ size: 'sm', sku: '1' }, { size: 'md', sku: '2' }] },
    { name: 'Product 2', variants: [{ size: 'lg', sku: '4' }] },
    { name: 'Product 3', variants: [{ size: 'sm', sku: '5' }, { size: 'lg', sku: '6' }] },
    { name: 'Product 4', variants: [{ size: 'sm', sku: '7' }] }
  ],
  filter = ['sm', 'md'];

const arr = t1
  // filter t1 elements variants
  .map(e => ({
    ...e,
    variants: e.variants.filter(({ size }) => !filter.includes(size))
  }))
  // filter resulting elements with no variants left
  .filter(({ variants }) => variants.length);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter each `variants` subarray by whether the size you want is included, then filter the whole `t1` array by whether the subarray contains items.

```js
const t1 = [
  {
    name: 'Product 1',
    variants: [
      { size: 'sm', sku: '1' },
      { size: 'md', sku: '2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 2',
    variants: [{ size: 'lg', sku: '4' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 3',
    variants: [
      { size: 'sm', sku: '5' },
      { size: 'lg', sku: '6' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product 4',
    variants: [{ size: 'sm', sku: '7' }],
  },
];

const filterBy = ['sm', 'md'];
for (const obj of t1) {
  obj.variants = obj.variants.filter(
    subobj => !filterBy.includes(subobj.size)
  );
}
const filteredInput = t1.filter(obj => obj.variants.length);
console.log(filteredInput);
```